# Change modification

Tags: netbeans

quick question, odes anyone know if Netbeans has line modification highlighting either built in or available through a plugin, that has to be available when developing with Netbeans for PHP.

example:

```
<?php echo'look'; ?>
```

then I save and change line 2

```
<?php echo'look I have changed'; ?>
```

I now want to see some kind of highlighting within Netbeans that this line has changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Versioning information is available in Netbeans 7.0 RC2, but not as a line highlight. To see the revision history, you can right-click a file and select "Local History -> Show Local History"

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans does this automatically with any supported version control system. I personally can confirm that there is nice highlighting of

- modifications (blue),
- additions (green) and
- removals (red)

for at least Mercurial and Subversion. If I remember correctly, Git support was added with NetBeans 7.0 recently (not sure, though).

Comment: you misunderstand I was not referring to version control modification it is more simple than that, any modification without SVN or GIT.

Comment: Then I'm sorry, I'm not aware of a way to do this with NetBeans without using a VCS. Maybe you can start using one?

Comment: trust me I want to but where I am do not use one, maybe this is a way to make them lol

Comment: @Deviland: Oh, then I'm with you. Good luck with establishing good practices wherever you are. :-)